# Null hypothesis of the Wald-Wolfowitz runs test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, runs

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test)

> The runs test (also called Wald–Wolfowitz test after Abraham Wald and Jacob Wolfowitz) is a non-parametric statistical test that checks a randomness hypothesis for a two-valued data sequence. More precisely, it can be used to test the hypothesis that the elements of the sequence are mutually independent.

1. I was wondering if its null hypothesis is that the elements of the
   sequence are iid? (note that the quote only mentions mutual
   independence.)
2. What if the sequence is three-valued?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: The part you've quoted only mentions mutual independence; but ten lines down:- "These parameters do not assume that the positive and negative elements have equal probabilities of occurring, but only assume that the elements are independent and identically distributed."

Comment: A trinomial runs test sounds interesting. The same statistic (number of runs from a sequence of length $n$) could be used but I don't know its distribution. Why don't you try to derive it (following the Wald-Wolfowitz derivation) or simulate it for a few different nulls & sample sizes & post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

For 3 or more sequences, it's called the k-Category Extension of the Runs test.  You can find a derivation here: https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Analysis_of_Runs.pdf

I wrote an R function to calculate the p-value as follows:

```
ww_test <- function(x) {
    x <- factor(x)
    n <- length(x)
    njs <- table(x)
    njs <- structure(.Data=as.vector(njs), .Names=names(njs))
    mu <- (n*(n+1) - sum(njs^2))/n
    sdev_l <- n^2*(n-1)
    sdev_u <- sum(njs^2*(sum(njs^2)+n*(n+1))) - 2*n*sum(njs^3)-n^3
    sdev <- sqrt(sdev_u/sdev_l)
    r <- sum(diff(as.numeric(x)) != 0) + 1
    z <- (r - mu) / sdev
    pvalue <- 2*pnorm(-abs(z))
    return(pvalue)
}
```